# MongoDB/ - Update Multiple Fields inside an array, keep their original value, but update datatype

Tags: c#, mongodb

So the problem I have is that I want to be able to filter on a particular criteria.

I originally tried to filter based on the datatype of the field, I am struggling to do this with arrays though.  This did work at one point with single fields, but now not having much joy.

Then as part of the update I want to set specific fields inside the array from string datatype to say integer.

So to summarise I want to do the following:

- Filter where the fields in the array are string datatype as I want to update them.
- Update only the datatype and retain the value(essentially converting from string to integer)
- Get results with modified count to ensure it was successful.

Thanks in advance.

```
var mongoDb = mongoClient.GetDatabase(config.DatabaseName); // , new MongoDatabaseSettings() { WriteConcern = WriteConcern.Unacknowledged }


        var objectId = new ObjectId("63d38c71ef08fde3fbf1b9da");
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", objectId);
        
        var updateQuery = new BsonDocument { { "$set", new BsonDocument { { "CheckFinalization.Check.ItemDetail.$[].ItemNumber", new BsonDocument { { "$toInt", "$CheckFinalization.Check.ItemDetail.$[].ItemNumber" } } } } } };
        var updatePipeline = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Pipeline(PipelineDefinition<BsonDocument, BsonDocument>.Create(updateQuery));

        var dataCollection = mongoDb.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(config.CollectionName);
        var recordResult = dataCollection.Find(filter).Limit(100).ToList();

        // check we have records to update.
        if (recordResult.Any())
        {
            var result = dataCollection.UpdateMany(filter, updatePipeline);

            if (result.ModifiedCount > 0)
            {
                // Success
            }
            else
            {
                // Failed
            }
            
        }`
```

Comment: `$toInt` is an aggregation operator, not an update operator, you will need to use the aggregation pipeline form of update.

Comment: I managed to do this by using JObject and JToken then switching out the data types and recreating the bson documents then inserting many in batches. It works, just not the most slickest of solutions.  Thanks for the help.